# On 1st render of application, there is a difference between what it was pre-rendered and rendered during the first render in the Browser. [Nextjs]

Tags: next.js, rendering, server-side-rendering, hydration

In a peculiar occurrence, an unusual effect can be observed during the initial rendering of the Navbar component. The appearance of the Navbar when it is first rendered differs significantly from its final rendered state.

Here is the Navbar code (works fine)

```
'use client';

import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import { listedPages } from './listedPages';
import AwdiwLogo from '../logo';
import Link from 'next/link';

const pages = ['Products', 'Pricing', 'Blog'];

function ResponsiveAppBar() {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);
  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Container maxWidth="100%" sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <AwdiwLogo />
          <Box
            sx={{
              flexGrow: 1,
              marginLeft: 'auto',
              display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
              justifyContent: 'right',
            }}
          >
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none', alignContent: 'flex-end' },
              }}
            >
              {listedPages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page.id} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Link href={page.path}>
                    <Typography textAlign="center">{page.name}</Typography>
                  </Link>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
          <Box
            sx={{
              flexGrow: 1,
              display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
              justifyContent: 'right',
            }}
          >
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}></Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
export default ResponsiveAppBar;
```

Here is the Logo component (here is the problem).

```
import { Container, Button, SVG } from './logoElements';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';

const AWDIWLogo = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Link href="/">
        <Button>
          <SVG viewBox="0 0 130 130" className="border">
            <polyline
              points="130,1 130,130 1,130 1,1 130,1"
              className="bg-line"
            />
            <polyline
              points="130,1 130,130 1,130 1,1 130,1"
              className="hl-line"
            />
          </SVG>
          <Image
            src="/test-logo.png"
            alt="All We Do Is Web Logo"
            width="129"
            height="129"
            hydrate
          />
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default AWDIWLogo;
```

Logo Styles

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container = styled.div`
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
`;

export const Button = styled.button`
  width: 130px;
  max-height: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    background: black;
  }
`;

export const SVG = styled.svg`
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150 540;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;

  ${Button}:hover & {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-dashoffset: -540;
  }
`;
```

Here is an image of the unexpected effect using slow 3g throttling.
[bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ah5i.png)

Here is an image of the end result (when is done rendering). This is the expected result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Oew.png)

Please let me know if what is could be the cause of this issue. Thanks!

I have tried adding 'use client' in all related files but it did not work.
I have tried relocating assets, but it did not work as well.